# Route53 CNAME record linked to CF distribution returns REFUSED

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-403, amazon-route53

I am new to AWS and I'm trying to create an API using API Gateway and Lambda (both automatically created by Claudia using my node application).

My API is working almost correctly using this address:
`https://********.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/latest` (the links are broken due to the /latest).

So I created a Custom Domain Name and I mapped / with `myapi:latest`.

Then I created a CNAME record in Route 53 linking `www.mywebsite.com` with the Target Domain Name that CDN gave me.

When I try to test that record inside of Route 53 (Test Record Set), I get a REFUSED response code and an  Response.

I've seen this [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) and I tried to create an A record instead of a CNAME record (linking my CloudFront URL to `www.mywebsite.com`). 
 This time the Test Record Set works and gives me back the IP addresses. When I try to access the website, I get a 403 Forbidden and I am redirected to `******.cloudfront.net`.

I've also seen [Custom domain for API Gateway returning 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466092/custom-domain-for-api-gateway-returning-403) but none of the solution is really helping me (unless I understand them in the wrong way). 
 
My CNAME in Route 53 pointed to my CloudFront distribution and my base path mapping is done.

What am I doing wrong? And what are the next steps I have to do?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466092/custom-domain-for-api-gateway-returning-403?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @GustavoTavares like I said, I've also seen this thread but none of the answers is helping me.

Comment: sorry... my bad.

Comment: Have you provided correct SSL certificate for your domain name ?